# Is this beetle on my apricot tree a pest?

Tags: fruit-trees, identification, insects, pests, apricots

My apricot tree is infested with black and white beetles on the branches. They are 2-3 cm / 1 inch long. I can't find an identification on the web. There is no visible damage to the tree. Is this beetle a pest? Should I be removing them?

My location is the Mediterranean / Middle East.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are there any signs of damage to the tree? *what state are u in? Try this link if nothing materializes here: http://bugguide.net/node/view/6/bgimage

Comment: Thanks - I updated the question with the relevant data you asked about. The link is for N. American bugs, so I couldn't find my friend there.

Comment: For those interested, this tree died in 2014 from this infestation.

Comment: What camera did you take these pictures with?

Comment: @Lanka Sony DSC-H3. Why do you ask?

Comment: It's a great low light macro shot. Very fine details. Just look at the little guys feet and body. And the veins on the leaf. Beautiful.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is. A good advertisement for Sony...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a [Capnodis tenebrionis (L.). - Peach Flatheaded Rootborer](http://www.agroatlas.ru/en/content/pests/Capnodis_tenebrionis/).

They seem to be fairly problematic, and HIGHLY UNWANTED.  They are very destructive to the plant.

> Larvae and adults damage saplings and young stone-fruit cultures. Adults devour cortex, leafstalks, and fruit buds. Orchard bushes lose their leaves after C. tenebrionis mass abundance. Economic significance is greater in southern arid regions, especially in Eastern Georgia, Armenia and Azerbaijan. Irrigation of orchards during oviposition period is one of the pest control measures because it destroys most eggs.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the species? It is entirely black, whereas the one in the photos is black and white; of course, it may change color at different stages in its development..

Comment: "black, sometimes with bronze shine".  Pretty certain that is what it is.  Everything seems to match with your situation.

Comment: I checked it out and that's definitely Capnodis.

Comment: Good Luck! hope it all goes well.

Answer (score 3):

Capnodis sexmaculata (Coleoptera; Buprestidae). In Balochistan, Pakistan it is a pest of Apricot and Almond